# Problem with reinstalling Facebook app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, install, facebook

I accidentally deleted my facebook app on my iPhone5. 
When i tried to download it again it says " Unable to download Facebook at this time."

What's wrong? How can this be resolved?

I already restarted the phone, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things that you can try. These will be non-technical answers to you question.

Go to `Settings>General>Date and Time` and toggle the Automatic switch. This will set the correct time for your iPhone, as sometimes the App Store does not download apps to iPhones with their clock set in the future.

Restart the iPhone by holding down on the lock and home button at the same time for about 10-15 seconds until the Apple Logo appears (there is no red slider) then let go of the buttons.

Sign out of the App Store in Settings, sign in again and try to download.

Sometimes, users have connection problems to the App Store (or the App Store has an internal problem) so wait and try again later. You can use Facebook in Safari in the meanwhile.

Mainly this error occurs when Apple changes their Policies and Terms, or when the wrong time is set on the iPhone, because the iTunes/App Store Session is invalid or has expired. So this should help you, otherwise let me know in a comment and I will try to help :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but even after doing some of those things you listed, though, the user may just have to wait until things are resolved on the App Store's end, should a connection issue or something like that be the problem.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 - thank you for the comment! I will add it to the Answer.

Comment: Still the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with your device. It's a app store problem...

The Solution is Open iTunes on your PC and go to App Store via iTunes and download Apps and Connect your iPad and install.. (Do this for temporary period) sometimes you will receive same error report when u download apps from iTunes.. Click retry to download and install...